# Building WHEN clause with a clojure expression in hugsql

Tags: clojure, hugsql

I have a database with a `status` entity that I'd like to be able to fetch in many different ways. As a result, I'd like to build the `WHEN` clause of my query based on the content of a map.

For instance, like this:

```
(get-status *db* {:message_id 2 :user_id 1 :status "sent"})
;; or
(get-status *db* {:message_id 2})
;; or
(get-status *db* {:user_id 1})
;; etc.
```

I'm struggling using hubsql's [clojure expressions](https://www.hugsql.org/#using-expressions). I am doing the following:

```sql
-- :name get-status
-- :doc fetch the status of a specific message
-- :command :query
-- :return :many
/* :require [clojure.string :as s] */
SELECT
    *
FROM
    message_status
/*~
(let [params (filter (comp some? val) params)]
  (when (not (empty? params))
    (str "WHERE "
      (s/join ","
              (for [[field value] params]
                (str field " = " (keyword field)))))))
~*/
```

However, here is how the request is prepared by hugsql:

```
=> (get-status-sqlvec {:message_id 2 :user_id 1})
["SELECT\n    *\nFROM\n    message_status\nWHERE ? = ?,? = ?" 2 2 1 1]
```

Whereas I want something like:

```
=> (get-status-sqlvec {:message_id 2 :user_id 1})
["SELECT\n    *\nFROM\n    message_status\nWHERE message_id = 2, user_id = 1"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get this working. The above code had two issues.

First, we have

```clj
(s/join ","
  (for [[field value] params]
    (str field " = " (keyword field)))
```

Since `field` is a keyword, this actually generates this kind of string: `:foo = :foo, :bar = :bar`. The keywords are then replaced by `?` by hugsql. What we want instead is build this kind of string `foo = :foo, bar = :bar`, which we can do with this code:

```clj
(s/join ", "
  (for [[field _] params]
    (str (name field) " = " field))))))
```

The second problem is that the `WHEN` clause is not even valid SQL. The above code ends up generating requests such as:

```sql
SELECT * FROM message_status WHERE foo = 2, bar = 1
```

The commas in the `WHERE` clause should be `AND`, so the final (working) code is:

```sql
-- :name get-status
-- :doc fetch the status of a specific message
-- :command :query
-- :return :many
/* :require [clojure.string :as s] */
SELECT
    *
FROM
    message_status
/*~
(let [params (filter (comp some? val) params)]
  (when (not (empty? params))
    (str "WHERE "
      (s/join " AND "
              (for [[field _] params]
                (str (name field) " = " field))))))
~*/
```